# Avoid correlated subqueries error in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a simple query to obtain the currency rate in use at the time a transaction was created:

```
SELECT t.orderid, t.date, 
 (SELECT rate FROM sources.currency_rates r WHERE currencyid=1 AND 
r.date>=t.date  ORDER BY date LIMIT 1) rate
FROM sources.transactions t
```

This triggers an error:

```
Error: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not 
supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming 
them into an efficient JOIN.'
```

I've tried with several types of joins and named subqueries, but none seem to work. What is the best way to accomplish this? Seems like a very common scenario that should be quite straightforward to implement in BQ's Standard Sql.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  t.orderid AS orderid, 
  t.date AS date, 
  ARRAY_AGG(r.rate ORDER BY r.date LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS rate
FROM `sources.transactions` AS t
JOIN `sources.currency_rates` AS r
ON currencyid = 1 
AND r.date >= t.date
GROUP BY orderid, date
```

Comment: Will `rate` be an array here?

Comment: Thanks the suggestion, but this one causes a resource limit error: "Error: Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 5 or higher required". - Gonna keep experimenting :)

Comment: Got it working! Just need to create smaller temp tables and work with them, thanks Mikhail!

Answer (score 10):

I've noticed similar behavior with other correlated subqueries. They are useful, but can't always be automatically modeled to JOINs by BigQuery.

Similar case which works:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, (
  SELECT AVG(temp) 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2017` b
  WHERE a.usaf=b.stn  
) temp
FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.stations` a
LIMIT 10
```

Doesn't work:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, (
  SELECT temp 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2017` b
  WHERE a.usaf=b.stn  
  ORDER BY da 
  LIMIT 1
) temp
FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.stations` a
LIMIT 10
```

Fix:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, ARRAY_AGG(temp ORDER BY da LIMIT 1) temp
FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.stations` a
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2017` b
ON a.usaf=b.stn  
GROUP BY 1
LIMIT 10
```

*(give me a public dataset, and I'll write a query that works with your data)*

Comment: What does `GROUP BY 1` mean? :-/

Comment: It means group by first column (i.e. `GROUP BY name`)