# BigQuery SQL: Embedding subqueries from View A as nested tables in View B

Tags: nested, google-bigquery

I'm trying to combine the data from two flat, related BigQuery views into single nested table architecture, using standard SQL

I have two similar tables:

**Analytics Data:** One row for every minute in global timespan

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
minute_index | users | users_new | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
     1312017 |     8 |         3 | ...
     1312018 |     9 |         2 | ...
     1312019 |     5 |         1 | ...
     1312020 |     3 |         0 | ...
     1312021 |     5 |         2 | ...
     1312023 |     4 |         3 | ...
     1312024 |     7 |         4 | ...
     1312025 |     6 |         3 | ...
     1312026 |     9 |         4 | ...
```

**Event Data:** One row for each external event that occurred

```
----------------------------------------
minute_index | event                   |
----------------------------------------
     1312019 | "TV Spot Broadcast"     |
     1312023 | "Radio Spot Broadcast"  |
     1312026 | "Radio Spot Broadcast"  |
```

I'm trying to join them together into one table, where each row in the new  table contains a subset of the Analytics table that spans that and some number of the following minutes (let's call it 5):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
minute_index | event                    | window_treated                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1312019 | "TV Spot Broadcast"      | minute_index | users | users_new |
                                        |------------------------------------
                                        |      1312019 |     5 |         1 |
                                        |      1312020 |     3 |         0 |
                                        |      1312021 |     5 |         2 |
                                        |      1312023 |     4 |         3 |
                                        |      1312024 |     7 |         4 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1312023 | "Radio Spot Broadcast"   | minute_index | users | users_new |
                                        |------------------------------------
                                        |      1312023 |     4 |         3 |
                                        |      1312020 |     3 |         0 |
                                        |      1312021 |     5 |         2 |
                                        |      1312023 |     4 |         3 |
                                        |      1312024 |     7 |         4 |
```

I actually have been able to construct nested tables like this, but only by building up and joining convoluted sets of intermediate tables that are *clearly* way more complicated than they should be, if I can only figure out how to do this sort of thing in a single query.

This is just one example of the various approaches I've tried...

```sql
SELECT
  ed.timestamp AS timestamp,
  ed.minute_index AS minute_index,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT 
     ad.minute_index, ad.users, ad.users_new
   FROM `my_project.my_dataset.analytics_data` ad 
   WHERE (ad.minute_index >= ed.minute_index) 
      AND (ad.minute_index < (ed.minute_index + 5))
   ORDER BY
      ed.minute_index) AS units_treated
FROM
  `my_project.my_dataset.event_data` ed
```

but it's also one of several that seemed *close*, but all lead to the same validator error:

```
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.
```

Comment: I've been able to find a small number of close-but-not-quite answers here, like this one -- [Avoid correlated subqueries error in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040472/avoid-correlated-subqueries-error-in-bigquery) -- but they generally don't provide enough guidance to where I need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ed.minute_index, 
  event, 
  ARRAY_AGG(ad) window_treated
FROM `my_project.my_dataset.event_data` ed
JOIN `my_project.my_dataset.analytics_data` ad
ON ad.minute_index BETWEEN ed.minute_index AND ed.minute_index + 5
GROUP BY ed.minute_index, event
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result will be as below

[image]

As you can see  - I literally followed the suggestion in error message `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.` and transformed `correlated subquery` into `JOIN`

Comment: Thanks so much, @mikhail -- I was actually hoping you might chime in.  ;)

And to be clear, I definitely _did_ understand that that was basically what I needed to do, but I'd tried several variations of exactly the approach you described, and have gotten repeatedly wrapped around the axle trying to figure out the exact syntax of using `ARRAY_AGG`, `ARRAY' with `GROUP BY`, `SELECT AS STRUCT`, etc.

Comment: sure. make sense. hope now that pattern will help you in future :o)

Comment: Actually, I think one of my core problems was just using `LEFT JOIN` out of habit, instead of a naked/inner `JOIN`. I had tried something _very_ similar to your suggestion, but continually got `LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.`

If I had had enough confidence in the _rest_ of my pattern, I might have immediately realized "I should just use an inner join", but I had just been flailing around enough at that point that it was just one more error that meant I needed to understand what the h-ll is going on.

Comment: @LaurentStanevich - i see you unaccepted the answer - any particular reason? just curious

Comment: No, not at _all_. I think it may have just been an erroneous click.


(Actually, now that I'm thinking about it, I think it may have been an issue with my newfangled touchscreen laptop. I was explaining your solution to my son -- a CS major who's interning with me this summer -- and I'm guessing I may have inadvertently tapped the checkmark as I was gesticulating excitedly at my screen.)

Comment: While I've now used smaller datasets to confirm that this pattern is exactly what I need, I've also immediately run into GCP resource constraints. I haven't been able to query my main view at all without waiting for several minutes, and then eventually receiving some form of an `API Error: Resources Exceeded`.

I've been trying to create partitioned/clustered tables to deal with that issue (I'll post a separate question on that front, if I can't work things out). In the meantime, this works in concept, but I haven't been able to put it into practice.

Comment: Even though title of your question has mention of views - the question itself has no any view at all (unless I missed it). I recommend you to post new question specific to view use and your issue with it!

Comment: I guess I don't understand why it matters, @mikhail -- I understand the difference between a "view" and a "materialized view"/"table", obviously, but does it make a difference whether 'Entity A' or 'Entity B' is one or the other, for the purposes of this discussion?

(If it does, then I'd _really_ appreciate an explanation.)

Comment: 1. Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum but rather Question /Answer type of Site 2. as I said already - post your real question where you provide all relevant details - and we will be glad to help / answer, your current question is fully answered and has nothing to do with views!