# SQL Query to find the last change prior to a given date

Tags: sql, database, datetime, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables, one with product change info and another with test info and I'm trying to build a query to find the last product change information prior to the test.

For example, in the data below for, each of the tests I want to return something like:

| product_sn | testtype | testdate | part_spec | changedate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC0001 | hot | 2021-01-01 13:00:00 | nylon | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| ABC0001 | hot | 2021-01-01 16:00:00 | steel | 2021-01-01 15:00:00 |
| ABC1234 | hot | 2021-01-01 18:00:00 | steel | 2021-01-01 17:00:00 |
| ABC1234 | cold | 2021-01-01 18:10:00 | steel | 2021-01-01 17:00:00 |
| ABC1234 | mid | 2021-01-01 18:20:00 | steel | 2021-01-01 17:00:00 |
| ABC0001 | hot | 2021-01-02 09:00:00 | brass | 2021-01-01 20:00:00 |
| ABC1234 | cold | 2021-01-01 19:00:00 | steel | 2021-01-01 17:00:00 |

I'm a bit of a noob in sql and can't quite figure out the best terms to search for elsewhere in stackoverflow :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Scratchpad.product
    (`ID` INT64,
    `product_sn` STRING,
    `part_spec` STRING,
    `changedate` datetime
    )
;
    
INSERT INTO Scratchpad.product
    (`ID`, `product_sn`, `part_spec`, `changedate`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ABC0001', 'nylon','2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'ABC0001', 'steel','2021-01-01 15:00:00'),
    (3, 'ABC0001', 'brass','2021-01-01 20:00:00'),
    (4, 'ABC1234', 'steel','2021-01-01 17:00:00'),
    (5, 'ABC1234', 'nylon','2021-02-01 00:00:00')
;


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Scratchpad.test
    (`ID` INT64,
     `product_sn` STRING,
      `testtype` STRING,
      `testdate` datetime
    )
;
    
INSERT INTO Scratchpad.test
    (`ID`, `product_sn`, `testtype`, `testdate`)
VALUES
    (1, 'ABC0001', 'hot','2021-01-01 13:00:00'),
    (2, 'ABC0001', 'hot','2021-01-01 16:00:00'),
    (3, 'ABC1234', 'hot','2021-01-01 18:00:00'),
    (4, 'ABC1234', 'cold','2021-01-01 18:10:00'),
    (5, 'ABC1234', 'mid','2021-01-01 18:20:00'),
    (6, 'ABC0001', 'hot','2021-01-02 09:00:00'),
    (7, 'ABC1234', 'cold','2021-01-01 19:00:00')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to this other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45041970/274349

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  t.ID AS ID, 
  t.product_sn,
  t.testdate as date, 
  t.testtype,

  ARRAY_AGG(r.part_spec ORDER BY r.changedate desc LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS part_spec,
  ARRAY_AGG(r.changedate ORDER BY r.changedate desc LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS part_change

FROM `Scratchpad.test` AS t
JOIN `Scratchpad.product` AS r
ON t.product_sn = r.product_sn 
AND r.changedate <= t.testdate
GROUP BY ID,product_sn, date, testtype
```

Comment: . . This is basically the last solution in my answer.  But importantly, this doesn't do a `LEFT JOIN`, which is the tricky part of your question.

Answer (score -1):

This can be a tricky problem in BQ.  One solution is:

```
select t.*,
       (select as struct p.part_spec, p.change_date
        from `Scratchpad.product` p
        where p.product_sn = t.product_sn and
              p.changedate < t.testdate
        order by p.changedate desc
        limit 1
       )
from `Scratchpad.test` t;
```

This may work, but BigQuery is sometimes finicky about inequalities in left joins and subqueries.

A more verbose approach is:

```
select array_agg(t order by p.change_date desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*,
       array_agg(p order by p.change_date desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)].*
from `Scratchpad.test` t left join
     `Scratchpad.product` p
     on p.product_sn = t.product_sn and
        p.changedate < t.testdate
group by t.id;
```

Comment: didn't quite work but it the BQ error message did give me some new leads and search terms.  Found this which is very similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040472/avoid-correlated-subqueries-error-in-bigquery

Comment: @MartinD . . . What was the error message?  There is a more efficient approach to solving this -- and one that is quite scalable.  I wasn't sure if it was needed in this case.

Comment: the first one was "Scalar subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values" so I just removed one of the columns being asked for.  Then the next error was "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN"  so I did a search on Correlated SubQueries and looked through a few solutions.