# Insert column based on row condition in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table a which contain data:

```
date       device  type  country  value
2022-10-02  iOS    user  England  20
2022-10-02 android hit   US       30
```

I want to add new column to table a based on query. here's the example of query result:

```
date       device  type  country  age
2022-10-02  iOS    user  England  49
2022-10-02 android hit   US       50
```

I want to add column age to table a but consider the date, device, type, and country.
the expected result like:

```
date       device  type  country  value age
2022-10-02  iOS    user  England  20    49
2022-10-02 android hit   US       30    50
```

Note: I not want create new table, just want to add one column to existing table. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the column

```sql
alter table Test.ABC
add column age int64
```

Then we fill the column.

```sql
update  Test.ABC as TBL
set age = (select min(age) from 
(Select "iOS" device  , "user" type  , 49 c union all Select "android","hit",50 ) as R
where TBL.device=R.device and TBL.type=R.type
)
where true
```

In most cases it is cheaper to build a new table.

Comment: how about there are thousand row?

Comment: for a 1000 row table a `update` is no issue. But the best way is to generate a new table if two tables are joined. The table `a` is obtained from some export/import to Bigquery. At a certain time you need to update this table or insert new data. Then everyone wonders why the column `age` is empty.

Comment: I've try and it works on joining another tables. but when FROM my query then `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported`

Comment: I tested it with a 70.000 row table and a reference table with 1 mio rows. The join has to find exactly one item. Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040472/avoid-correlated-subqueries-error-in-bigquery  But in your case take a `min()` and a `group by 1`